# Minimal Repository implementation using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement a minimal generic repository pattern in my application. I have a really small interface for querying and saving data:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() 
        where TEntity: BaseEntity;

    void Save<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
        where TEntity : BaseEntity;
}
```

`BaseEntity` is a base class for all the objects I will store in my repository:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to find a working implementation of such a simple repository using Entity Framework, but it was surprisingly hard to find (people are using `UnitOfWork` and other things that make the implementation more complex than I want).

So I created the absolutely minimal implementation I could come up with:

```
public class EfRepository : DbContext, IRepository
{
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return this.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public void Save<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        if (entity.Id == default(Guid))
        {
            entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }       

        this.SaveChanges();
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } // User is a subclass of BaseEntity
    //Other DbSet's...
}
```

Now, my question is if such implementation is correct. I'm asking because I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm worried about possible performance issues or things that could possibly go wrong while using such repository.

Note: I'm trying to do all this for 2 reasons:

- For testing purposes, so that I can create a mock of the repository in my unit tests projects
- It's possible that I'll have to switch to another ORM in the future, and I'd like to make this transition as easy as possible.

Comment: It might be worth considering if EF is the right ORM to use if you are after a light touch and have performance concerns. From personal experience I haven't found EF to be very performant in any of the projects I've used it in, and it's a bit clunky keeping its mappings in line with the DB or Code (depending on which path you choose, code or DB first). 

Anyone I know who works in high throughput environments physically wince whenever anyone mentions EF.

Comment: The question really is: since EF *already* implements the repository (`DbSet<T>`) and unit-of-work (`DbContext`) patterns - why reinvent the wheel with yet another layer on top of that??

Comment: @marc_s, I have 2 reasons :) Please, see my edit

Comment: Reason #1 is unnecessary in EF6 - you can easily mock `DbSet<T>` and `DbContext` with Rowan Miller's [EntityFramework.Testing](https://github.com/rowanmiller/EntityFramework.Testing/wiki) NuGet package ....

Comment: I'm still waiting for a real world example of reason 2. YAGNI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all repositories are controversial. There are lots of people strongly against and lots using it (or used to it?) for various reasons. There many articles over the internet with endless discussions about pros and cons. It's up to you to decide if you actually need the repository pattern in your project - let's not focus on that as you asked "how to do that in C#?" not "should i do that?".

Your repository implementation extends `DbContext`. This means you cannot effectively create a transaction spanning more than one repository (more than one entity type) because each repository will have it's own `DbContext` (as it IS the context). Under the hood `DbContext` tracks changes made to the entities. If you have more than one context and try to save both at the same time they won't know about each other. This leaves us with a problem - if the first call of `SaveChanges()` succeeds and second fails how to rollback the first one? It was already saved?. That's where the unit of work appears.

So first you need a repository interface - acting as a collection of entities:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void AddAll(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);

    void Remove(TEntity entity);
    void RemoveAll(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities);
}
```

And unit of work:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    // Commit all the changes 
    void Complete();

    // Concrete implementation -> IRepository<Foo>
    // Add all your repositories here:
    IFooRepository Foos {get;}
}
```

Base classes could look as follows:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected DbContext Context { get; private set; }

    public BaseRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        Context = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if(entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }

    public void AddAll(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach(var entity in entities)
        {
            Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
        }
        Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public void RemoveAll(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Remove(entity);
        }
    }

}
```

And Unit of work implementation:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private IFooRepository _fooRepo;

    public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;

        // Each repo will share the db context:
        _fooRepo = new FooRepository(_dbContext);
    }


    public IFooRepository Foos
    {
        get
        {
            return _fooRepo;
        }
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: _you cannot effectively create a transaction spanning more than one repository_ - this is not entirely true. I can create a `TransactionScope` and wrap it around all the necessary repository calls. By default (without the transaction scope) my repository implementation will commit all the changes with every call of `Save`, and this default behavior is what I need in most cases.

Comment: Your `Save()` will cammit all modified entities from all repositories using the same `DbContext`, regardless on which repo you will call it.