# Generic Repository with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I'd like to implement a generic repository pattern using Entity Framework (I know there are many controversial opinions about repositories, but still this is what I need).
The interface I'd like it to have is as follows:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() 
        where TEntity: Entity;

    void Save<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
        where TEntity : Entity;

    void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
        where TEntity : Entity;
}
```

`Entity` is a base class that just has an `int ID` property.
And to use it like this:

```
        IRepository repository = ... // get repository (connects to DB)
        int userId = GetCurrentUserId();
        if (!repository.Query<User>().Any(u => u.Id == userId)) // performs SELECT query
        {    /*return error*/    }

        var newOrder = new Order { UserId = userId, Status = "New" }
        repository.Save(newOrder); // performs INSERT query
        ...
        newOrder.Status = "Completed";
        repository.Save(newOrder); // performs UPDATE query
```

I'd like to avoid `UnitOwWork` and just commit all object changes to the DB once `Save()` or `Delete()` is called. What I want to do looks really simple, but I haven't found any examples of how to do it using EntityFramework.The closest example I could find is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40626876/5678122), but it uses `UnitOwWork` and repository-per-entity, which is more complicated than what I need to do.

Comment: If you want to keep it simple then do not use a repository pattern with Entity Framework. Entity Framework itself is already a repository pattern, you are only adding more abstraction on top of an existing abstraction and it has no benefit. In contrary it will probably make your code much more difficult to maintain and to use while adding the cost to develop an additional unnecessary layer.

Comment: This is not a generic repository, it's just a wrapper around a DbContext. I'm curious how you're implemented `Save`, because it suggests that you can selectively save one entity, even when the context contains more changed entities. Hard to believe. And if you can, this defeats the purpose of the `SaveChanges` method.

Comment: @GertArnold, the interface _is_ a repository. And I _have_ implemented parts of it using pure ADO.NET and Dapper. (BTW that is one of the reasons why I want an abstraction over EF: some parts of my application contain complex queries not fully supported by EF, but I want all the queries to be executed using one abstraction: IRepository) IRepository doesn't know or care about  EF or DbContext. It is supposed to be a common simple interface for all data manipulation (which can be very complex under the hood - like using different ORMs for different entity types).

Comment: @Nazz IQueryable<T> will "infect" your code using the IRepository interface with the implementation (f.i. EF). It is not as abstract anymore

Comment: @Nazz so you're saying that behind your repository abstraction you can have EF or Dapper?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria, I'm saying that I can use Dapper for _some_ queries (i.e. if `(Entity is XXX) QueryWithDapper() else if(Entity is YYY) QueryWithNHibernate() else QueryWithEf()`). Obviously, Dapper cannot be used as a full implementation of this interface, as it doesn't support `IQueryable`.

Comment: @SirRufo, IQueryable =! EF, For example, NHibernate supports it too

Comment: @Nazz, in that case I keep with the tech that offer me the minimum common denominator ie Dapper.

Comment: Well, call it a repository (which is disputable enough). It's not a *generic* repository. You can manipulate any type by one repository instance. It's just a class with generic methods, which makes its function very unclear. If you do `Delete(order)` and `Save(customer)` using the same instance it's not clear to me what happens. I wouldn't like this kind of ambiguity.

Comment: @GertArnold, I'm not sure I understand what is unclear. If you do Delete(order); Save(customer), you should end up with 2 queries: `DELETE FROM Orders WHERE Id=x`,`UPDATE Customers SET ... WHERE Id=x;` If any query fails (i.e. DELETE returns 0 rows), the repository should throw an exception and not roll back any previous updates.

Comment: @Nazz There is **no** guarantee that an EF IQueryable will behave in the same way as an IQueryable from anything else. You also cannot do anything with an EF IQueryable, there are some limitations because it has to be converted into a sql statement. Read http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/221541

Answer (score 3):

1-Create One Interface

```
interface IMain<T> where T : class
    {
        List<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(int id);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Edit(T entity);
        void Del(int id);
        int Savechange();
    }
```

2-Create One Class

```
public class Main<T> : IMain<T> where T : class
    {
        public DataContext db;
        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Del(int id)
        {
            var q = GetById(id);
            db.Set<T>().Remove(q);
        }

        public void Edit(T entity)
        {
            db.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public List<T> GetAll()
        {
            return db.Set<T>().Select(a=>a).ToList();
        }

        public T GetById(int id)
        {
            return db.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }

        public int Savechange()
        {
            return db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

3-Create One Repository With Name YourTable ForExample **Student**

```
 public class Student : Main<Tbl_Student>
    {
        public Student()
        {
            db = new DataContext();
        }
    }
```

4-To Your Action Write This Code

```
Student student=new Student();
student.Del(3);
int a = student.Savechange();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with expression keyword;

```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);

        void Save(TEntity entity);

        void Delete(TEntity entity);
    }

    public abstract class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity
    {
        private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
        public EfRepository(YourDbContextContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null) return;
            else
            {
                DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = _dbContext.Entry(entity);

                if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
                {
                    dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }
                else
                {
                    _dbSet.Attach(entity);
                    _dbSet.Remove(entity);
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _dbSet.Where(predicate);
        }

        public void Save(T entity)
        {
            if (entity.Id > 0)
            {
                _dbSet.Attach(entity);
                _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                _dbSet.Add(entity);
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then create your repositories;

```
     public interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
     {
       //Also you can add here another methods according to your needs
     }
     public class UserRepository : EfRepository<User>,IUserRepository
     {
            public UserRepository(YourDbContext yourDbContext) : base(yourDbContext)
            {

            }
     }
```

Then use it;

```
IUserRepository _userRepository => Getit
//If there are entities according to your conditions, this will return them, then use it
_userRepository.Query(u => u.Id == userId);
```

Comment: Can we use `IEntity` instead of `where T : Entity`?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use it but as many developers have said it will add more complexity to your code and can cause problems:

Code for my `interface IRepositoryBase`:

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    void Add(TEntity objModel);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> objModel);
    TEntity GetId(int id);
    Task<TEntity> GetIdAsync(int id);
    TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync();
    int Count();
    Task<int> CountAsync();
    void Update(TEntity objModel);
    void Remove(TEntity objModel);
    void Dispose(); 
}
```

Code for implementatation of my `interface` on the repsoitory `RepositoryBase`:

```
public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepositoryBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    #region Fields

    protected readonly EntityContext _context = new EntityContext();

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Add(TEntity objModel)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(objModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> objModel)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(objModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public TEntity GetId(int id)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
    }

    public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Where<TEntity>(predicate).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetListAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Where<TEntity>(predicate));
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => _context.Set<TEntity>());
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Count();
    }

    public async Task<int> CountAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().CountAsync();
    }

    public void Update(TEntity objModel)
    {
        _context.Entry(objModel).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity objModel)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(objModel);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My entities `interface`:

```
public interface IMyEntityRepository : IRepositoryBase<MyEntity>
{
     //here you can place other implementations your repository doesn't have
}

public class MyEntityRepository : RepositoryBase<MyEntity>, IMyEntityRepository
{
}
```

How to call it (I was using dependency injection):

```
public class MyServiceOrController
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IMyEntityRepository _myEntityRepository;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public MyServiceOrController(IMyEntityRepository myEntityRepository)
    {
        _myEntityRepository = myEntityRepository;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public IList<MyEntity> TestGetAll()
    {
        return _myEntityRepository.GetAll();
    }

    #endregion
}
```